# Difference in atomic orbitals and one electron system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The text from my textbook states:

“ The wave function is a mathematical function whose value depends upon the coordinates of the electron in the atom and does not carry any physical meaning. Such wave functions of hydrogen or hydrogen like species with one electron are called atomic orbitals. Such wave functions pertaining to one electron species are called one-electron systems. The probability of finding an electron at a point within an atom is proportional to the $|\psi|^{2}$ at hat point “.

Both the statements appear same to me. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the definition given in the text, Atomic orbitals and one electron systems are the same.

---

I want to comments on what is written in the text:

> The wave function is a mathematical function whose values depend upon the coordinates of the electron in the atom and don't carry any physical meaning.

Quoting the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function),

A wave function in quantum physics is a mathematical description of the quantum state of an isolated quantum system. The wave function is a complex-valued probability amplitude, and the probabilities for the possible results of measurements made on the system can be derived from it.

On a position basis,  if the wave function is interpreted as a probability amplitude, the square modulus of the wave function, the positive real number

$$|\Psi(x,t)|^2=\rho(x,t) \ \ \text{ the probability density that the particle is at x}$$